# Troubleshooting "Unexpected T_ECHO" in ternary operator statement

Tags: php, ternary-operator

```
($DAO->get_num_rows() == 1) ? echo("is") : echo("are");
```

This dose not seem to be working for me as intended, I get an error "Unexpected T_ECHO". I am expecting it to echo either 'is' or 'are'.

I have tried it without the brackets around the conditional. Am I just not able to use a ternary operator in this way?

The `$DAO->get_num_rows()` returns an integer value.

Comment: Consider to use templates, not direct output from the business logig

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The Ternary operator is not identical to an if-then.  You should have written it

```
echo ($DAO->get_num_rows() == 1) ? "is" : "are";
```

It **returns the value** in the 2nd or 3rd position.  It does NOT **execute the statement** in the 2nd or 3rd position.

Comment: If it returns the value, why if you replace `echo` by `print` it works?

Comment: @Mageek -- it "works" ? Or it does not die? Just because it prints something does not mean that it does what OP wanted. My recommendation should so what was intended.

Comment: I wanted to understand why `($DAO->get_num_rows() == 1) ? print("is") : print("are");` works, but `($DAO->get_num_rows() == 1) ? echo("is") : echo("are");` doesn't.

Comment: @Mageek: I don't know for certain, but if I had to guess I would say that 'print' returns a value, so it's fine, but 'echo' does not return anything and therefore the function does not work.

Comment: still helping me alot

Answer (score 6):

The ternary operator should result in a value -- and not echo it.

Here, you probably want this :

```
echo ($DAO->get_num_rows() == 1) ? "is" : "are";
```

If you want to use two `echo`, you'll have to work with an `if`/`else` block :

```
if ($DAO->get_num_rows() == 1) {
    echo "is";
} else {
    echo "are"
}
```

Which will do the same thing as the first portion of code using the ternary operator -- except it's a bit longer.

Answer (score 2):

The ternary operator *returns* one of two values after evaluating the conditions. It is not supposed to be used the way you are using it.

This should work:

```
echo ($DAO->get_num_rows() == 1 ? "is" : "are");
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use

echo ($DAO->get_num_rows() == 1) ? "is" : "are";