# php / apache2 - shorthand if (bug - discussion, finding an explanation)

Tags: php, linux, performance, apache, virtual-machine

This is something very weird I could not explain, but probably some of you already found the same or a similar issue?

Imagine the following pseudo PHP code:

```
<?PHP

  mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");
  mysql_select_db("mydb");
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT id, my_name FROM my_table");

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {

      $row[1] ? echo $row[1] : echo $row[0];

  } 

  mysql_free_result($result);

?>
```

This basically just queries the mySQL server and iterates through all recordsets.
It then uses a "shorthand" if statement to find out if there is something in column `my_name`. If there is, it will print it, if not, it will print the `id` instead.

Now the weird part, on a Debian Linux virtual machine, running on an ESX5 this shorthand if takes 10 times longer than a normal `if{}else{}` statement.

So instead of 3 seconds in my case (iterating 5000 records), it takes 30 seconds on this particular VM - the same code on an ESX4 Debian host is running just fine.

If I replace the shorthand IF with the normal IF statement, everything's fine.

I did some research on the Internet, but couldn't find an explanation.
Where would you start searching for the issue?

Thank you!
// Markus

Comment: Just curious but what is the speed comparison if you use echo $row[1] ? $row[1] : $row[0];

Comment: Start testing...eliminate mysql from the equation. build an array of the results, then do loop on the array so no mysql calls are made.

Comment: Make the test ^^ upwards of a few million tries to average out the speed correctly.

Comment: It should really be: echo ($row[1] ? $row[1] : $row[0]); Having echo within a ? is extremly odd.

Comment: oh, it really should be `echo ($row[1] ? $row[1] : $row[0])` - I will rerun the tests to see if this makes a difference. (rtfm :))

Comment: what's interesting is that PHP doesn't throw an exception because of the wrong syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, my fault - I should have read the manual on ternary operators before using them "out of my head"...

I changed the operator to the correct format as  **Acyclic Tau** and  **MTilsted**  mentioned in the comments:

```
$output .= ($row[1] ? $row[1] : $row[0]);
```

The strange speed issue is gone - but the next question is why PHP is not throwing an exception because of the wrong syntax?

Comment: because its not actually syntactically wrong. The statement "echo $row[1]" is being executed and evaluated to a value and then that is being temporarily copied. A by product of this evaluation is that your script does echo the required result.

Comment: Actually I am not entirely sure my above statement is correct, echo is not a function but a language construct, so while it will be evaluated to void, it maybe considered syntactically incorrect. Maybe somebody else could provide a definitive answer.

Comment: Interesting read: [stackoverflow-2698372](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698372/troubleshooting-unexpected-t-echo-in-ternary-operator-statement) - the OP did get an unexpected T_ECHO error, whereas I'm not. BTW, I'm on PHP 5.3.3-7

Comment: okay, did some tests - as I wrote "pseudo" code, I used echo inside the ternary operator - that does actually throw an "unexpected T_ECHO" - but in the real code I've used a variable like that: `$row[1] ? $output .= $row[1] : $output .= $row[0];` - if you are using the ternary operator this way, it does not throw any expections - but is wrong syntax, though.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a fundemantal difference between the ternary operator (?) and an IF statement (as described here http://fabien.potencier.org/article/48/the-php-ternary-operator-fast-or-not) the summation is basically:

The speed of the ternary operator is directly related to the time it takes to copy the result of the statement, even if it is not strictly needed. And copying an array of 100000 elements takes time.

This is due to that fact that the ternary operator copys the value to a new memory location, where as the if..else block may not.

While this may explain the difference in speed on the single instance of a VM, it does not sufficiently explain why the two VMs differ in speed when both using the ternary operator.
Assuming the two VMs you are using are on different hardware. Is it possible you are using differing versions of PHP? That the underlying processor is different between the two hosts and is impacting the processing speed of the memory copy?

Comment: great research, thank you; yes, the two VMs have different physical CPUs and hardware - they both are running the exact same virtual image of the server, so PHP version is the same. What's interesting is that you see a lot of mmap2(NULL) calls if I strace the apache process while running the loop.