# Why does the ternary operator work with print but not with echo in php?

Tags: php, printing, echo, ternary-operator

This works:

```
$number = 1;
$number == 1? print 'yes' : print 'no';
```

but this doesn't work:

```
$number = 1;
$number == 1? echo 'yes' : echo 'no';
```

Why is this happening in PHP?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2698372/3933332

Comment: In short, it only accept operations that has a return value, like `print`.

Comment: Also as always see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Comment: According to my testings it doesn't matter if it returns a value or not. I've created a function "foo" and inside it I wrote just an echo (without returning a thing), then I used that "foo" function instead of print, and even it doesn't return a thing, it works.

Comment: @user3646717, see my answer for your latest comment.

Comment: @user3646717 Every function returns something! If you do `var_dump(foo())` you will get null.

Comment: Oh ok, I got it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters to the ternary operator have to be expressions. `print 'yes'` is an expression, but `echo 'yes'` is not, because `echo` is special syntax.

Use the ternary operator as the argument of `echo`, not the other way around.

```
echo $number == 1 ? 'yes' : 'no';
```

It's the same reason you can't write:

```
$var = echo 'yes';
```

Comment: Thank you Barmar, do you know how can I distinguish special syntax from everything else, is there any link where I can read further about this topic?

Comment: @user3646717 You can tell from the documentation. It says that `print` returns `1`, which means it must be an expression. But the documentation of `echo` says that it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Thanks again Barmar.

Answer (score 0):

Check your log for a warning. The ternary operator *must* return a value. `print` returns `1` *always*, but `echo` does not return a value.

Regarding your comment about putting `echo` in a function, functions that don't explicitly return a value return `null` by default, therefore, the function is indeed returning a value:
http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php